# IntelliJ IDEA dictionary settings for IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to add spelling dictionary not on project settings level, but for whole IDE? I find setting this for every project little annoying.

Comment: This is very weird, thanks for raising it. I just opened 2 projects, and added a new word to the dictionary in project A. Miraculously, the same word became valid in project B, even though it doesnt appear in the list of "Accepted Words", and even after closing and re-opening both projects. To add to the weirdness, Spelling -> Typo disabled itself in project B.

Comment: @vikingsteve, it happens because of the [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52948).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thx! I'll bookmark youtrack for future search :)

Answer (score 6):

You can configure dictionaries for the [default project](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/accessing-default-settings.html). All the new projects will inherit this configuration.

Comment: Thx, I missed this option.

Answer (score 2):

**IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1**

File > Other Settings > Default Settings... > Editor > Spelling > Dictionaries tab

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few years, and it's there in the IDE settings. Don't know if it's going to be useful, posting it anyway for anyone searching for it now and in the future.

[image]

Once application-level dictionary is chosen, the IDE will then start saving words into `cachedDictionary.xml` in `{IDEA_CONFIG_DIR}/config/options`. Then you can simply add new words globally by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and selecting `Save to Application Level Dictionary` in the context menu.

[image]

Comment: but it still sucks.
In almost 2023 I'd expect to be able to create a project-level dictionary, configure its location in .editorconfig and share it with my team.

IntelliJ is going to be the second Eclipse.